# Invalid Identifier, cannot run JOIN query

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to run the following code to JOIN esrb rating and platform to the GAME table but failed:

```
select distinct ntdo_stage.title, ntdo_stage.meta_score, ntdo_stage.user_score, ntdo_stage.link, ntdo_stage.date2, ntdo_stage.platform, ntdo_stage.esrb_rating
      from ntdo_stage
      left join ntdo_platform 
      on (ntdo_platform.platform_id =ntdo_game.platform_id)
      left join ntdo_esrb_rating
      on (ntdo_esrb_rating.esrb_rating_id =ntdo_game.esrb_rating_id) 
      where title is not null
```

got the following error message:

```
ORA-00904: "NTDO_GAME"."PLATFORM_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 159 Column: 38
```

DDL for ESRB_RATING TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE ntdo_esrb_rating (
    esrb_rating    VARCHAR2(10),
    esrb_rating_id NUMBER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ntdo_esrb_rating ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_esrb_rating_pk PRIMARY KEY ( esrb_rating_id );
```

DDL for PLATFORM TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE ntdo_platform (
    platform_id   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    platform_name VARCHAR2(55)
);

ALTER TABLE ntdo_platform ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_platform_pk PRIMARY KEY ( platform_id );

ALTER TABLE ntdo_game_developer
    ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_game_dev_fk FOREIGN KEY ( developer_id )
        REFERENCES ntdo_developer ( developer_id );
```

DDL for the GAME TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE ntdo_game (
    game_id              NUMBER NOT NULL,
    game_name            VARCHAR2(55),
    meta_score           VARCHAR2(10),
    user_score           VARCHAR2(10),
    link                 VARCHAR2(150),
    platform_id          NUMBER NOT NULL,
    esrb_rating_id       NUMBER,
    release_date         DATE,
    release_date_comment VARCHAR2(55)
);

ALTER TABLE ntdo_game ADD CONSTRAINT ntdo_game_pk PRIMARY KEY ( game_id );
```

DDL for the STAGE TABLE:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "MASY_CW3956"."NTDO_STAGE" (
    "META_SCORE" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "PLATFORM" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "DATE2" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "USER_SCORE" NUMBER(38,1), 
    "LINK" VARCHAR2(256 BYTE), 
    "ESRB_RATING" VARCHAR2(26 BYTE), 
    "DEVELOPERS" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE), 
    "GENRES" VARCHAR2(128 BYTE)
) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
STORAGE (INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
TABLESPACE "USERS"
```

I have already made sequence for platform_id, esrb_rating_id, and game_id.

Comment: this query can never produce that error, also you missed some table, thos looks more loke a placeholder like python uses

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. what do you mean by I missed some tables?

Comment: see the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7d53656914328a0342563ed9cf35a6e2 the query doesn't run with your provided tables  but this is not a sql problem at all

Comment: wow! thank you so much! this websites looks awesome tho.

Comment: Where is the stage table ddl?

Comment: the "platform_id" in the game table is a foreign key... not sure how to use JOIN to join the platform_id in the platform table with the platform_id in the game table, might have to look up the foreign key ( platform_id) but not sure how to do it... just added the DDL for stage table!

Answer (score 1):

Your join clause `(ntdo_platform.platform_id =ntdo_game.platform_id)` references the `ntdo_game` table, but you are not joining to that table in this query. You need to include that table in your `from` clause.

If you have a `game_id` column in the `ntdo_stage` table, your query would look like this:

```
select distinct   
    ntdo_stage.title
   ,ntdo_stage.meta_score
   ,ntdo_stage.user_score
   ,ntdo_stage.link
   ,ntdo_stage.date2
   ,ntdo_stage.platform
   ,ntdo_stage.esrb_rating
from   
    ntdo_stage
    left join
    ntdo_game on NTDO_STAGE.game_id = ntdo_game.game_id
    left join
    ntdo_platform on (ntdo_platform.platform_id = ntdo_game.platform_id)
    left join
    ntdo_esrb_rating on(ntdo_esrb_rating.esrb_rating_id = ntdo_game.esrb_rating_id)
where title is not null;
```

Comment: !! thank you so much!! but how to add that table in my from clause after the "ntdo_stage"? Sorry this may sound dumb but i am actually new to sql ...

Comment: You'll need a relationship between the `NTDO_STAGE` and the `NTDO_GAME` table. I would expect to see a `game_id` column in the DDL for the `NTDO_STAGE` table

Comment: There is no game_id column in the "NTDO_STAGE" :( but I made a sequence for game_id, will that work? I uploaded the csv to the stage table, I couldn't change the original csv file so there is no game_id in NTDO_STAGE.

Comment: I guess the big picture question would be, why do you need to join to any other tables for this query? All the joins are `left join` and only columns from the `ntdo_stage` are referenced in the `select` and `where` clauses

Comment: Because my professor said I can use JOIN to look up the foreign key. Thank you so much for helping me. I think I will ask him again.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because your query is using the table `ntdo_stage` which does not seem to exist (at least in the tables that you gave us).

You will also receive an error about the `title` column because none of the tables have a title column.

It seems like you are mixing up some of your tables.

Comment: I do have a ntdo_stage table. But in the stage table the title column is the same as game_name in my other tables